# Mongodb aggregate to sort items with most common items in array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

An item in collection contains an array of strings. I would like to find and sort items with most matching elements in array.

Consider a collection:

```
[
    {
        "item_name":"Item_1",
        "tags":["A","B","C","D","E"]
    },
    {
        "item_name":"Item_2",
        "tags":["A","B","D","E","G"]
    },
    {
        "item_name":"Item_3",
        "tags":["B","C","E","H"]
    }

]
```

I want to sort the collection based on an array like ["B","D","G","F"]
which will return

```
[

    {
        "item_name":"Item_2",
        "tags":["A","B","D","E","G"]
    },
    {
        "item_name":"Item_1",
        "tags":["A","B","C","D","E"]
    },
    {
        "item_name":"Item_3",
        "tags":["B","C","E","H"]
    }

]
```

The expected order will be Item_2,Item_1 and then Item_3 since,

- Item_2 matches 3 items ("B","D" and "G")
- then Item_1 with 2 matches ("B" and "D")
- finally Item_3 with 1 match ("B")

If not in mongodb, JavaScript methods will also be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the values in `tags` are unique, you can use the size of the intersections of `tags` and the query array using [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      matchedCount: {
        $size: {
          $setIntersection: ["$tags", ["B","D","G","F"]]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      matchedCount: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. This was accurate.
Can you also suggest how to discard items which do not match with at least 1 tag

Comment: Let's say you are searching for `["B","D","G","F"]`, when you say "items that do not match at least 1 tag", does that mean `["A","D","G","F"]` or `["B","D","G","F","H"]` or ["D","G","F"]?

Comment: I meant something else like ["H","K","L"]

Comment: You can add `{ $match: { tags: { $in: ["B","D","G","F"] } } }` at the start of the pipeline

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) to get the number of intersecting items and then [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) based on the computed score.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      item_name: "$item_name",
      tags: "$tags",
      score: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            intersection: {
              $setIntersection: [
                "$tags",
                [
                  "B",
                  "D",
                  "G",
                  "F"
                ]
              ]
            }
          },
          in: {
            $size: "$$intersection"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      score: -1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tpDTtVKetFT